# CRT to key and csr backward

Tags: ssl, x509

1. I have generated RSA PRIVATE KEY .KEY and Certificate sign request .CSR
2. Then i load thoose files into CA and got .CRT(DER) file and Root_CA.CRT (PEM) file
3. Then i convert .CRT(DER) using RSA PRIVATE KEY .KEY to .CRT (PEM)
4. I generate .pfx (PKCS#12) from .CRT (PEM) using RSA PRIVATE KEY .KEY

And now i loosing RSA PRIVATE KEY .KEY and Certificate sign request .CSR

Question:
Is that possible to restore RSA PRIVATE KEY .KEY and Certificate sign request .CSR from .CRT(DER) or .CRT (PEM), having Root_CA.CRT (PEM) file?

Comment: If you still have the PKCS12/PFX file _that_ contains the private key, which you can extract if you remember the password.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `no`. You cannot recover private key or CSR from public certificate. And having CSR won't help you either, you cannot recover private key from CSR. Neither of them (public certificate nor CSR) have private key information.

Comment: If anyone _could_ recover privatekey from a cert, everything on the Internet and nearly alll computers would be totally insecure and either the Internet would not exist or civilization would have ended. Most people would probably have noticed either of those events.